# Combine arrays into one group

Tags: php, arrays

Sorry for probably stupid question but really need your help. I have got the array:

```
{"code":200,"message":"OK","0":{"title":"Green peppercorn and lemongrass coconut broth","media":"\/posts\/images\/84709.jpg"},"1":{"title":"Green peppercorn and lemongrass coconut broth","media":"\/posts\/images\/84709.jpg"}}
```

And need to achieve this:

```
{"code":200,"message":"OK","records":[{"title":"Green peppercorn and lemongrass coconut broth","media":"\/posts\/images\/84709.jpg"},{"title":"Green peppercorn and lemongrass coconut broth","media":"\/posts\/images\/84709.jpg"}]}
```

Please let me know how to do it with PHP...it used to be two arrays I merged with `array_merge($message, $records);`

Thank you

Comment: How about `$message["records"] = $records`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to continue with your `json` response then you can create a new array as like, but this example is only work for your `json` which you mentioned in your question:

```
<?php
$array = json_decode('{"code":200,"message":"OK","0":{"title":"Green peppercorn and lemongrass coconut broth","media":"\/posts\/images\/84709.jpg"},"1":{"title":"Green peppercorn and lemongrass coconut broth","media":"\/posts\/images\/84709.jpg"}}
',true);

$newArray = array(); // initialize new array 
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if(is_array($value))    { // if having array
        $newArray['records'][] = $value;
    }
    else{
        $newArray[$key] = $value;
    }
}
echo json_encode($newArray);
?>
```

**Result:**

```
{"code":200,"message":"OK","records":[{"title":"Green peppercorn and lemongrass coconut broth","media":"\/posts\/images\/84709.jpg"},{"title":"Green peppercorn and lemongrass coconut broth","media":"\/posts\/images\/84709.jpg"}]} Second, if you are mergin two array `array_merge($message, $records);`
```

**Second Solution (recommended)**, if you are combining two array and wants to add a new index `records` then you can also modify by adding a `records` index as:

```
$newArray = $message;
$newArray['records'] = $records;
echo json_encode($newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a short code (one string , two with $result declaration)

```php
$json = '{"code":200,"message":"OK","0":{"title":"Green peppercorn and lemongrass coconut broth","media":"\/posts\/images\/84709.jpg"},"1":{"title":"Green peppercorn and lemongrass coconut broth","media":"\/posts\/images\/84709.jpg"}}';
$result = [];
foreach(json_decode($json,true) as $k=>$v) if(is_array($v)){$result["records"][]=$v;} else {$result[$k]=$v;};
```

Make sure to change $json with your json

result (pretty_printed):

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "message": "OK",
    "records": [
        {
            "title": "Green peppercorn and lemongrass coconut broth",
            "media": "\/posts\/images\/84709.jpg"
        },
        {
            "title": "Green peppercorn and lemongrass coconut broth",
            "media": "\/posts\/images\/84709.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```